# Why is the answer to an integral different for |x|<1 despite the original answer working for this condition as well?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I can't seem to understand why the answer for this same integral yields a different answer with the condition of |x|<1 even though this condition works for both answers regardless?

- Example given in notes:

[image: Example given in notes]

- Question on the HW with what the answer is supposed to be on the right]:
  [image: Question on the HW with what the answer is supposed to be on the right]

In general, I don't seem to understand how to change my answer for such conditions other than trying to use algebra on the answer to eliminating the part that leads to undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both the integrals are different.**

In the first integral you have $\color{blue}{\arctan(x)}$ and $x^2$ and both are defined for all $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$. So the integral can be evaluated for $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

Whereas in the second integral you have $\color{blue}{\arcsin(x)}$ and $x^2$. Although $x^2$ exists for all $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$, $\color{blue}{\arcsin(x)} $ is defined only for $\color{blue}{-1\le x\le 1}$ or $\color{blue}{|x|\le 1}$, so the integral is limited to $|x| \le 1$

Comment: Oh my god, thank you I must have copied it down wrong the first time and never realize it!

Comment: You're welcome!